# Where is this quote about overcoming the impossible said in "Interstellar"?

Tags: dialogue, interstellar

On IMDb, [a quote](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0816692/quotes/qt2084353) from *Interstellar* says:

> Cooper: We've always defined ourselves by the ability to overcome the impossible. And we count these moments. These moments when we dare to aim higher, to break barriers, to reach for the stars, to make the unknown known. We count these moments as our proudest achievements. But we lost all that. Or perhaps we've just forgotten that we are still pioneers. And we've barely begun. And that our greatest accomplishments cannot be behind us, that our destiny lies above us.

I watched *Interstellar* and did not hear it. Where is it said in the movie?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It wasn't said in the movie as far as I know. It's from the first teaser trailer:

For the record, IMDb *usually* labels those with a "[from trailer]" disclaimer, but didn't here for some reason.

Comment: That was fast!!

Comment: @Aaron I often browse IMDb quotes, and those sometimes have a "from trailer" label. I checked yours didn't, and as you were sure it wasn't in the movie, I figured it would come from promotional material (it was fitting for a trailer, too). YouTube did the rest :)

Comment: I almost feel like this was just taken from one of his awkward Lincoln car commercial performances and crammed into the "Interstellar" setting.